# How to using loop for with java script for check value in input?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

How to use a  for loop in javascript to check for valid input?

I've tried my code but it does not work, how can I fix it?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
<span id="price_top"></span>
<a href="#" id="addScnt_price" style=" cursor: pointer; font-weight: bold; color: #0192B5; text-decoration: none; ">Add more</a>
<div id="p_scents_price">
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function checkform ( form )
{
var z = 1;
for(z=0;z<10;z++) {
  if ((form.price'+z+'.value != "") && (form.price'+z+'.value < "1.5")) {
    alert( "Minimum Price'+z+' $1.5" );
    document.getElementById("price_top").scrollIntoView()
    document.getElementById("price'+z+'").style.border = "1px solid red";
    return false ;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("price'+z+'").style.border = "1px solid #d5d5c5";
  }
}
return true ;
}
</script>

<script>
$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents_price');
        var i = 1;

        $('#addScnt_price').live('click', function() {
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts_price"><input type="text" id="price'+i+'" size="20" name="price[]"/><a href="#" id="remScnt_price">Remove</a></label></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });

        $('#remScnt_price').live('click', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                }
                return false;
        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't open a string with `"` and terminate it with `'`.
You had to review your element id refers.
For example, you need to change:

```
document.getElementById("price'+z+'") ...
```

With:

```
document.getElementById("price"+z) ...
```

You also have to change this:

```
form.price'+z+'.value ...
```

With

```
eval("form.price"+z).value ...
```

[eval function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)

Comment: And how to apply loop for ?